# Incompatibility between memoir and pdfpages ?

Tags: packages, memoir, pdfpages, draft

I am including a single pdf page (the title of my thesis) with the package `pdfpages` :

```
\begin{document}          
\includepdf{title.pdf}
...
```

But since I switched from `report` to `memoir` the page is not included, the first page of the resulting pdf if a blank page where "title.pdf" appears.

Do you know if there is an incompatibility between these two packages ?

Comment: Incidentally, memoir contains lots of options for creating custom title pages itself. This might be worth doing, since it will give you a more consistent look to the whole thing...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two packages can work together.

I think of these possible causes:

- You use a `draft` class (or package option). In this case, the pdf page will not show up but the file name `title.pdf` would be printed instead. That fits to your description.
- You use LaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX. When compiling to DVI, pdfpages would just insert an empty page. On could accidentally switch the output profile (easy in TXC).

I guess the first point might be the case, so I would check the document class option at first.

Comment: You were right about `draft` ! Thanks.